# How to get rid of "var1" and rename "var2" as "Variable?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently making RShiny project which displaying the summary of choosen variable. However, I can't get rid of this "var1" and can't rename "var2". How I supposed to do? I'm new at this field. TIA.

This is my code:

```
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                navbarPage(
                  # theme = "cerulean",  # <--- To use a theme, uncomment this
                  "My first app",
                  tabPanel("Navbar 1",
                           sidebarPanel(
                             selectInput(inputId="option",
                                         label="",
                                         c("CHILDREN","FHEAD","FEMALE","ELDERLY","FAMILYSIZE","NOELECTRIC","LOWEDU","GROWTH","POVERTY","ILLITERATE",
                                           "NOTRAINING","DPRONE","RENTED","TAPWATER","NOSEWER","POPULATION"),
                                         selected="CHILDREN"),
                             
                             
                           ), # sidebarPanel
                           mainPanel(
                             tableOutput("table")
                           ) # mainPanel
                           
                  ), # Navbar 1, tabPanel
                  tabPanel("Navbar 2", "This panel is intentionally left blank"),
                  tabPanel("Navbar 3", "This panel is intentionally left blank")
                  
                ) # navbarPage
) # fluidPage


# Define server function  
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  sum <- reactive({
    data <- data %>%
      select(input$option) %>%
      summary() %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =Stat, values_from = Value)
  })
  
  output$table <-renderTable(sum())
} # server


# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where is `data` defined?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't really have anything to do with Shiny, but in the data manipulation you are doing inside your server code.

We can replicate your problem without creating a Shiny app by setting up like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data  <- iris
input <- list(option = "Species")
```

Now when we run your code we have an unwanted column called Var1, and we have the Var2 column that you want renamed:

```r
data <- data %>%
  select(input$option) %>%
  summary() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =Stat, values_from = Value)

data
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   Var1  Var2            `setosa    ` versicolor `virginica `
#>   <fct> <fct>           <chr>        <chr>      <chr>       
#> 1 ""    "      Species" "50  "       "50  "     "50  "
```

We can improve this with a few tweaks. Firstly, we can just `select` out the `Var1` column. Secondly, we can `rename` the `Var2` column. Thirdly, we trim the unwanted whitespace from the entries in our table, and finally, we remove the whitespace from our variable names:

```r
data  <- iris

data <- data %>%
  select(input$option) %>%
  summary() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(-Var1) %>%
  rename(Variable = Var2) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), trimws)) %>%
  tidyr::separate(Freq, c("Stat", "Value"), sep=":") %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =Stat, values_from = Value) %>%
  setNames(trimws(names(.)))

data
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   Variable setosa versicolor virginica
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>      <chr>    
#> 1 Species  50     50         50
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>